# Como retorna apenas o nome do arquivo, sem o caminho

Tags: php

Galera como faço para esse código me retornar apenas o nome do arquivo.

Com esse código atual ele ta me retornando todo o caminho do arquivo ex:

arquivos/IES.pptx

Eu preciso que ele só retorne o nome ou o nome com extensão Ex:

IES ou IES.pptx

Segue o código.

```
<?php
// Recupera a lista de todos os arquivos:
$itens = glob("arquivos/*");

// Ordena os arquivos pela data de modificacão:
usort($itens, function ($a, $b) { return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b); });

// Pega apenas os cinco últimos modificados:
$cont = array_slice($itens, 0, 5);

foreach ($cont   as $arq )

echo  "<a href=  ".$arq." > ".$arq." </a><br>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um `basename` apenas deve resolver:

```
<?php
// Recupera a lista de todos os arquivos:
$itens = glob("arquivos/*");

// Ordena os arquivos pela data de modificacão:
usort($itens, function ($a, $b) {
   return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b);
});

// Pega apenas os cinco últimos modificados:
$cont = array_slice($itens, 0, 5);

foreach ($cont as $arq) {
    $nome = basename($arq);
    echo '<a href="' . $arq . '"> '. $nome . '</a><br>';
}
```

Ou (depende do que você quer):

```
$nome = basename($arq);
echo '<a href="' . $nome . '"> '. $nome . '</a><br>';
```

Se quiser sem a extensão (se os arquivos forem todos do mesmo formato):

```
<?php
// Recupera a lista de todos os arquivos:
$itens = glob("arquivos/*");

// Ordena os arquivos pela data de modificacão:
usort($itens, function ($a, $b) {
   return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b);
});

// Pega apenas os cinco últimos modificados:
$cont = array_slice($itens, 0, 5);

foreach ($cont as $arq) {
    $nome = basename($arq, '.pptx');
    echo '<a href="' . $arq . '"> '. $nome . '</a><br>';
}
```

Se tiver extensões variadas:

```
<?php
// Recupera a lista de todos os arquivos:
$itens = glob("arquivos/*");

// Ordena os arquivos pela data de modificacão:
usort($itens, function ($a, $b) {
   return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b);
});

// Pega apenas os cinco últimos modificados:
$cont = array_slice($itens, 0, 5);

foreach ($cont as $arq) {
    $nome = pathinfo($arq, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    echo '<a href="' . $arq . '"> '. $nome . '</a><br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode combinar [strrchr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php) que retorna a última parte de uma string após o delimitador (ele entra junto como retorno) e `trim()` para remover a `/` restante.

```
$arr = array('public/html/p1/js/f.js', 'p2/main/file.txt', 'p3/readme.txt', 'pics/1.jpg');

foreach ($arr as $item) {
    echo trim(strrchr($item, '/'), '/') .'<br>';
}
```

Saida:

```
f.js
file.txt
readme.txt
1.jpg
```

Outra opção é a usar função [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php), o segundo argumento diz para ela retornar apenas o nome do arquivo. A pasta, extensão e o nome sem extensão são outras opções.

```
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    echo  pathinfo($item, PATHINFO_BASENAME) .'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para obter o nome do arquivo, a partir do caminho completo:

```
 $this_page = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); // caminho e nome do arquivo
 if (strpos($this_page, "?") !== false) $this_page = reset(explode("?", $this_page));
```

Comment: Jovem, de onde você tirou isso? A pergunta fala sobre sistema de arquivos, e não de url. Eu negativei sua resposta, porque ela não faz sentido aqui.

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` retorna o caminho do php rodando e veio de carona. O restante do trecho `basename()` e o `if` é que resolvem a questão.  Alias, `basename()` está na base da resposta aceita. Na próxima, serei mais explicito... Ou talvez não.

Comment: O problema é que isso não tem nada a ver com o que foi perguntado